# Redirect to FB messanger bot with text message.

Tags: messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

I am redirecting the user from my website to 3rd party FB messanger bot. Let us take an example of a [weather](https://www.messenger.com/t/hiponcho) bot. The simple  workflow is: 
1. User click on the bot link .
2. User is on messanger bot page.
3. User types in his city name say Zurich and gets the weather report for it.

In my scenario I already know user's city i.e. Zurich. Is it possible for me to send city name (text message) along with redirect to [weather](https://www.messenger.com/t/hiponcho) bot so that user does not have to type it. I already looked into [send api](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-messages/#sending_text), but can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you redirect to the bot with an m.me link you can include the city in the ref param. The ref is delivered to your webhook in a messaging_referrals or messaging_postbacks event, depending on whether the chat is new or existing. The bot can then parse that ref and return the appropriate message.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/discovery/m-me-links